# How to use react unstated outside of render method?

Tags: reactjs, unstated

I am using ustated library in my project.

In render method, I am using `set` like this:

```
render() {
    return (
            <ApiSubscribe>
                {api => (
                    <button content='CLICK ME' onClick={() => api.setMessage('RENDER CLICK')} />
                )}
            </ApiSubscribe>
    )
}
```

How can I call `api.setMessage` OUTSIDE of render? For example in `componentDidMount` ?

ApiSubscribe is:

```
export const ApiSubscribe = props => {
    // We also leave the subscribe "to" flexible, so you can have full
    // control over your subscripton from outside of the module
    return <Subscribe to={props.to || [Api]}>{props.children}</Subscribe>;
};
```

Comment: [Looking at everything that the library exports](https://github.com/jamiebuilds/unstated/blob/master/src/unstated.d.ts), I don't think you can.

Comment: pass `api` down to a child component as a prop, and use its `componentDidMount` hook or whatever

Answer (score 6):

Like this?

```
class Child extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    this.props.api.setMessage('hey')
  }
  render {...}
]

let Parent = () => (
  <ApiSubscribe>
    {api => <Child api={api} />}
  </ApiSubscribe>
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a HOC to wrap your component, then pass the container from the HOC component to the child component in the form of props.

Comment: Simple and effective. Thanks.

Comment: can you give an example of this?