# JSX syntax arrow function inside render

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I just saw this code in [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51573978/how-to-use-react-unstated-outside-of-render-method#51574457) and i don't understand how it works :

```
let Parent = () => (
  <ApiSubscribe>
    {api => <Child api={api} />}
  </ApiSubscribe>
)
```

I understand something like this:

```
let Parent = ({api}) => (
  <ApiSubscribe>
    <Child api={api} />
  </ApiSubscribe>
)
```

but never saw `{foo => <Bar bar={bar} />}` in render before,

can someone help me understand this?

Comment: If you want to pass arguments to the children, this pattern is useful because you can do `props.children(api)` in `ApiSubscribe` and pass the argument `api`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A component can access the child elements given to it with the `children` prop. If a function is given as child, the component can call this function. The component calling the `children` function can then call the function with any argument it sees fit.

**Example**

```js
const Child = props => {
  return props.children('test');
};

const Parent = () => (
  <Child>
    {function(arg1) {
      return <div> This is a {arg1} </div>;
    }}
  </Child>
);

ReactDOM.render(<Parent />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: thank's for this explanation, but something is not clear for me, if instead of `{function() { ...`I write `{function(foo) { ...` what will `foo`contains ? Child's props?

Comment: @Jayffe You're welcome! I updated the answer. The component itself can call the `children` function with whatever arguments it likes. It differs from library to library that use this technique.